# object for my simple money recording app

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I am trying to make an app where people owe money to each other. let say person buy movies tickets for his friends and each ticket cost was 20 dollar. Now every one of his friend owe that person 20$.

I did made an object but, i think it is not right way to approach it. I would like know if there is a better way i can do it.

for Example
person1 to person2: $20.
person3 to person2: $20.
person2 to person1: $0.
person2 to person3: $0.

i have approached like this

```
    var person1 = new User(1, "person1", [{"name": "person2", "amount": 0}, {"name": "person3, "amount": 0}]);
var person2 = new User(2, "person2", [{"name": "person1", "amount": 0}, {"name": "person3, "amount": 0}]);
var person3 = new User(3, "person3", [{"name": "person1", "amount": 0}, {"name": "person2", "amount": 0}]);
```

Comment: Not to demotivate you from creating, but you realize this already exists? https://venmo.com/

Comment: I don't think the OP is planning on releasing this commercially. I often code experiments to see how things work/for fun, to push my understanding of how existing apps work. Keep up the good work, Ismail.

Comment: I am just coding it for fun. I am learning node, express and hogan. So just using this application idea to get my hands dirty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend to tie the "transactions" to the user itself. Keep them separately. Maybe just like this.

```js
// just an quick example using typescript

class User {
  public readonly id: string;
  public readonly name: string;
  
  constructor(name?: string) {
    this.name = name || 'unknown';
    this.id = Math.random(); // just an example;
  }
}

class Transaction {
  private target: string;

  public readonly date: number;
  public readonly origin: string;
  public readonly amount: number;
  
  constructor(origin: User, target: User, amount: number) {
    this.date = Date.now();
    this.origin = origin.id;
    this.target = target.id;
    this.amount = amount;
  }
  
  public changeTarget(user: User) {
    this.target = user;
  }
}

class TransactionManager {
  private static instance: TransactionManager;
  private transactions: Transaction[] = [];
  private users: { [id: string]: User } = {};
  
  public getInstance() {
    if (!TransactionManager.instance) {
        TransactionManager.instance = new TransactionManager();
    }
    return TransactionManager.instance;
  }
  
  public createUser(name) {
    let user = new User(name);
    this.users[user.id] = user;
    return user;
  }
  
  public lendMoney(from: User, to: User, amount: number) {
    let transaction = new Transaction(from, to, amount);
    this.transactions = this.transactions.concat(transaction);
    return transaction;
  }
  
  public getUserDept(user: User) {
    if(!this.users[user.id]) {
      throw new Error('user not found');
    }
    return this.transactions.reduce((dept: number, t: Transaction) => {
      return t.origin === user.id ? dept + t.amount : dept;
    }, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will consider it and separate it from the user.